# Is team Id in Slack is tied to a workspace? Can we create multiple teams in a workspace?

Tags: slack, slack-api

admin.users.list [List users on a workspace]

users.list [Lists all users in a Slack team]

What will be the difference in these two response?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation and compared the sample responses for each of these endpoints? These sections in the docs are quite detailed and should answer your questions regarding what "*the difference*" between them is. Beyond that's it not clear what Stack Overflow can provide as an answer to this question that the documentation does not. See [ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[admin.users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.users.list) allows using same admin token to read members of different slack workspaces,

whereas, when using [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list), you need different access token for getting members from each slack workspace.

Also, the response of `users.list` method is more verbose: 
 https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list#examples

 as compared to `admin.users.list`:
 https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.users.list#examples

Answer (score 0):

Per the [slack FAQ](https://api.slack.com/faq#workspace-naming), `team_id` is the ID for a workspace; they are the same.

Regarding your second question, per @Suyash's answer, it has to do with the tokens for enterprise grid customers, with `admin.users.list` allowing you to access all workspaces under an organization with the same token.